# Multinomial Naive Bayes

Tags: bayesian, classification, naive-bayes, pattern-recognition

I'm looking for an article, program, algorithm that can clearly explain whats going on inside a **Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier** compared to a **Gaussian Naive Bayes Classifier**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you have a for a two-class problem a classifier with equally costs for the each type error has the Bayes rule defined by choose class 1 if $f_1(x)/f_2(x)>1$ and class 2 otherwise where $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are the two class conditional densities.  This decision boundary is determined by the specific class conditional densities for the problem.  If the classifier is Gaussian then the densities will be multivariate Gaussian.  For other distributions the class boundaries will be different because the densities are different.  In the case of the multinomial the distributions are discrete rather than continuous.